# Is there a Module to edit php just like live css?

Tags: 7

I have downloaded Live css and it seems to be very good for editing . I am new to drupal and I don't know all where the php files are stored . is there any Module to edit php just like what live css does ? :  please any help will be essential

Comment: What php files are you talking about?

Comment: like html.tpl.php

Comment: Nope there isn't. And if there was, I'm sure the _Drupal Security Team_ would have made sure it isn't supported. Something like this would create a major security hole, wouldn't it?

Comment: @AjitS appreciated the info

Comment: Also by the time your page rendered, you'd not really be able to do anything with PHP. PHP is done on the server, processes the result and then spits it out.  Once it gets to your browser, it's "done" and you can't manipulate it like you would with CSS.

Comment: @jdu now I understand